# Instantaneous event for DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem check changed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I am currently using DevExpress 11.2 within Visual Studio 2010. Currently I am using two DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem which gives me two check boxes (with a label) in my menu bar (DevExpress.XtraBars.Bar) at the top of my windows form. Right now I have working code so that when one checkbox is clicked it unchecks/checks the other checkbox and executes code specific to that box. This works.

My problem is that the DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem does not have a check changed event. Currently I am using the EditValueChanged event as the checked check box is set to True and the unchecked checkbox is set to false. However the EditValueChanged event isn't called until the checkbox looses focus. This doesn't work for me as I want it instantaneous. I looked into the itemClick and ItemPress events but they don't give me the new editvalue and if someone presses on the caption (rather than the box portion) it still fires. Is there someway to get the event right away??

I am looking in two different older projects (both in Visual Studio 2008 and using DevExpress 9.2 and 10.2) and it looks like it does everything the same way as me yet the EditValueChanged event fires right away without any lose of focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually what you want to do is use the events on the repositoryCheckEdit that is in the BarItem, rather than the barEditItems events directly.  It will have CheckChanged and CheckStateChanged Events that you can use.

The repository Item that you want to use for the events will be listed in the Edit property of the BarEditItem.

In Code:

```
    Dim item As New DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem
    Dim Editor As New DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit
    item.Edit = Editor
    AddHandler Editor.CheckedChanged, AddressOf RepositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckedChanged
```

Comment: Thank you. Will have to try this when I get back :D

Comment: This is just translated, given the age of the answer I can't promise it still applies. DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem item = new DevExpress.XtraBars.BarEditItem();
var Editor = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
item.Edit = Editor;
Editor.CheckChanged += RepositoryItemCheckEdit1_CheckChanged;